# Is there a way to add a black outline to text in Kingdom Come Deliverance?

Tags: mods, kingdom-come-deliverance

It's so hard to read the text for the quick updates (e.g. quest updates, etc) because the text is white and blends in with the sky. I always have to look down on the ground to read it. I was wondering if there was a way to add a black outline so it makes reading them easier? Can I modify some configuration or maybe even a mod?

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.nexusmods.com/kingdomcomedeliverance ?

Comment: @breversa Yup, first thing I did when I encountered this issue. Sadly, unless I'm just blind, there's nothing there that fixes my problem.